# Binary search on String array can't pick upper case items

Tags: android, arrays

I m using Arrays.binarysearch on a string array in an android app. 
my array has 10 items, one of them being an UPPER CASE entry. Now, I can get index of all items from the array, except for the upper case one, which shows arrayIndexOutOfBound exception.
 For details: I m developing an android app with two activities. **Activity A** contains a list populated by an a string-array( called *infections*). When a user clicks an item on the list, he is taken to Activity B. The item clicked is sent to Activity B via putStringExtra method with the list's OnItemClickListener. In Activity B I am trying to get the received item's index on the same string-array (*infections*). All the other items work fine, except for one which is in UPPER case (the fifth item on the array... AIDS). Here are important snippets of my code:
**strings.xml**

```
<string-array name="infections">
            <item>Acne vulgaris</item>
            <item>Actinomycosis</item>
            <item>Acute otitis media</item>
            <item>African sleeping sickness</item>
            <item>AIDS</item>
            <item>Amebiasis</item>
            <item>Anthrax</item>
</string-array>
```

**ActivityA.java**

```
String[] infections = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.all_inf);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String clicked = adapter.getItem(position);
                Intent i = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
                i.putExtra(CLICKED_STRING,clicked);
                startActivity(i);
            }
    });
```

**ActivityB.java**

```
String[] infections = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.all_inf);
String received = getIntent().getStringExtra(ActivityA.CLICKED_STRING);
int index = Arrays.binarySearch(infections,received);
```

When the item "AIDS" is clicked on the list, the app gives an arrayIndexOutOfBounds exception. when i replace "AIDS" with "Aids", the app works fine. Any help??

Comment: Must. Show. Code. ;)

Comment: Is the array sorted?

Comment: @DanielNugent no the array is not sorted.

Comment: Do you have to keep that element in uppercase format? If not, you could force all of the entries to be lowercase before entering the binary search.

Comment: @BinaryJudy it has to be in upper case because its an acronym like AIDS. I will upload the code shortly. Thanks to all for such quick replies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need a sorted array for `binarySearch()`.

Documentation:

> public static int  binarySearch (Object[] array, Object value)
>
> Added in API level 1
>
> Performs a binary search for value in the ascending sorted array
>   array. Searching in an unsorted array has an undefined result. It's
>   also undefined which element is found if there are multiple
>   occurrences of the same element.
>
> Parameters
>
> array  the sorted array to search.
>
> value  the element to find.
>
> Returns the non-negative index of the element, or a negative index
>   which is -index - 1 where the element would be inserted.

Without seeing your code, I assume you are trying to do something like this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class BinarySearch
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String[] array = {"hello", "there", "YOU"};

    Arrays.sort(array);

    int index = Arrays.binarySearch(array, "you");

    System.out.print(array[index]);
  }
}
```

Which will give you this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -4
>       at BinarySearch.main(BinarySearch.java:18)

Basically, the element wasn't found, so it's returning a negative index as described in the documentation.  Then if you try to access index -4 in your array, of course you get an index out of bounds exception.

So first of all, make sure that you don't access a negative index in your array.
Also, you could do something like this to check for the uppercase version if the lowercase version of a String doesn't exist in the array:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class BinarySearch
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String[] array = {"hello", "there", "YOU"};

    Arrays.sort(array);

    int index = Arrays.binarySearch(array, "you");

    if (index < 0){
      String str = "you";
      index = Arrays.binarySearch(array, str.toUpperCase());

    }

    if (index >= 0){
       System.out.print(array[index]);
    }

  }
}
```

Edited after comment:

It seems like this approach would be better for what you need, just go through the list using a for loop:

Keep your ActivityA code as it is in the question.

ActivityB:

```
String[] infections = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.all_inf);
String received = getIntent().getStringExtra(ActivityA.CLICKED_STRING);
int index = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < infections.length; i++){
  if (received.equals(infections[i]){
      index = i;
      break;
  }
}

if (index != -1){
   //use index
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question, kindly take a look thanks.

Comment: I pass string item instead of int because I m using EditText with TextWatcher to filter the list (as a way of searching the list) in Activity A, after which the position of the items is changed and wrong index  is passed to the next activity. By the way I tried Arrays.sort, which doesn't show outOfBoundException, however, the item's index now shown is 0, instead ot its expected 4..... anyhow, thanks for your time

Comment: @drwisdom, just updated the answer again.  I think this approach will work better for you.

Comment: Yes, The for loop works.. I still wonder why binarySearh won't pick upper case letter. Anyhow, my problem is solved with for loop, thanks. accepted as answer